# Is it possible to prevent vim from quitting from the status of QuitPre autocommand? (e.g. prevent close on syntax issues)

Tags: vim

I know that it is possible to use QuitPre to expedite quits (e.g. if there are no "ordinary" buffers left), but is it possible to have a "safety check" for a file that was just modified?

Applications of this would be:

- checking that gitconfig is still valid before leaving
- checking that sudoers file is still valid before leaving
- checking that the crontab is still valid before leaving
- checking that ALE has no errors for the given file before leaving

I make quick edits to ~/.gitconfig all the time, and it's quite jarring when it breaks and I have to navigate to it & edit it again later. It would be nice to run a quick check before absent-mindedly `:wq`'ing out of it and moving on.

EDIT:

- echoerr does not seem to block it
- opening a new tab seems to block it, but that's pretty cumbersome. It can't even be used for a "re-open", since it blocks the original close in that case. It's a bit of a Catch-22.

In a filetype plugin:

```
augroup TestGitConfigBeforeExit
  autocmd!
  autocmd  
  \ QuitPre
  \ <buffer>
  \ *
  \ call system("git config -l") | if v:shell_error == 0 | echom "Safe to quit" | else | echoerr "invalid gitconfig" | tabe ~/SCRATCH  | endif
augroup END
```

Comment: All of those checks should be made on `BufWritePre`, `BufWritePost`, or even `BufWriteCmd` for maximum control (and complexity). `QuitPre` comes too late. Though the real cause of your troubles is you doing things "absent-mindedly" therefore the real solution would be to start paying attention to what you are doing.

Comment: Unfortunately you're wrong, BufWritePre/BufWritePost won't block the exit process even if they throw, and `QuitPre` is the cleanest implementation. Anyways I figured out a cheap hack that makes it work. As for your snipe, I don't know about your development process, but the point of one-off config changes is to be as "absent-minded" as possible. If I wanted to check syntax I'd become a linter.

Comment: I never implied that `BufWritePre|Post|Cmd` blocks the exit process, throwing or not.

Answer (score 0):

Alright this feels incredibly stupid so if someone else can think of a better solution, please post it for others:

```
augroup TestGitConfigBeforeExit
  autocmd!
  autocmd  
  \ QuitPre
  \ <buffer>
    \ call system("git config -l") 
    \| if v:shell_error == 0 
    \| echom "Safe to quit" 
    \| else 
    \| tabe %:p
    \| tabclose #
    \| echoerr "invalid gitconfig; fix before quitting" 
    \| endif
augroup END
```

No idea why tabe seems to block it, but it does. The `tabclose #` at least cleans-up the duplicate tab. This should be an extensible solution for any kind of "make sure I did not break the file before I quit-out and move on".